# JQL to find tests in multiple testsets with label

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to list all tests with a specific label from multiple testsets with a specific label.

issue in testSetTests("project-5683") and labels in (automation) and labels not in (Automation_Completed)

How do I perform this search in multiple testsets without listing them all in the JQL? The testsets I want to use all have a label I can use for this search.